# Creating an array within an object

Tags: c#, arrays, object

What i would like to do is create an object, then use the set and get's, and place it in an array within the object.  Is this possible?  So from my example below i have the sets and get's for the bar name, but then i want to store the name and locaion in an array within the object to be accessed at a later time.  Is this possible?

```
public class barlist
{
    private string barName;
    private string barLocation;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return barName; }
        set { barName = value; }
    }

    public string Location
    {
        get { return barLocation; }
        set { barLocation = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you would want to do this?

Comment: You want to place the object within an array that is within the object?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you completely. Why don't you just make a `Bar` class and then use a `List<Bar>`?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Do you want to be able to store instances of your class inside an array that you can access through  the class? Or, do you want to be able to access the properties of your class in an "indexed" fashion?

Comment: You could very well do this, but what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I guess I could make many differetn objects for each bar.  Howerver, how do I dynamically creat an object?  For instance.  If I want the object name to be the bar name and the name is from a text box or a list, it doesn't like it.  E.g  barlist item.text = new barlist() doedsn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Possible yes - reasonable no.
Either the array should be a static attribute of the class or a separate class.
You want to have just one array, otherwise the removal of one bar would mean modifications to all instances of the bar.

Comment: The resaon why i was doing this was to hold all the bar names and locations. Is there a way I can create an object out of just the bar name dynamicaly?  For instance. If I want the object name to be the bar name and the name is from a text box or a list, it doesn't like it. E.g barlist item.text = new barlist() doedsn't work

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment, exactly what you want is confusing. I THINK that what you want is to be able to reference a list of Bars as a member of any one Bar. That's simple enough; what you want is a static member:

```
public class barlist
{
    ...

    public static List<barlist> listOfBars;
}
```

Then, you can create bars and add them to the list:

```
var bar = new barlist();
barlist.listOfBars.Add(bar);
```

You can make your "barlist" class appear to *be* the collection instead of metrely *having* a collection by implementing the IList interface, which enforces the implementation of methods to add, remove, and access bars in the List. You can simply "pass through" these calls into a private List, and if you want any object to have the same list, make that list static.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure what do you want to accomplish but yes you can define an array of your object this could by strongly type for your class or using only objects. You can use this three structures

1. `ArrayList` <-- this handle differents types of objects
2. `List<barlist>` <---- this handle only objects from class `barlist`
3. `barList[] blah = new barList[10] ;` <--- define a array of 10 item of class barList

Answer (score 0):

you can use for example a static list in the class and add each object to the list in the constructor

Eg (on your code)

```
public class barlist
{
    private string barName;
    private string barLocation;
    public static List<barlist> myBarArray = new List<barlist>();
    public string Name
    {
        get { return barName; }
        set { barName = value; }
    }
    public barlist()
    {
      myBarArray.Add(this);
    }
    public string Location
    {
        get { return barLocation; }
        set { barLocation = value; }
    }
}
```

Now every time you create a barlist object, the object will be added in the List.

You can then access each barlist barName and barLocation.